# Backup FTP to Google Drive

Tags: backup, automation, ftp, google-drive

Can anyone suggest the best way to backup a website remotely and automatically (preferably through FTP) to Google Drive?

I have looked at [Mover](http://mover.io/) but it is expensive for FTP - I am looking for a free or cheap solution to backup my websites.

Comment: There are no such tools *preferably through FTP* because [Google Drive does not support FTP access](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/tqmLjdQ3FOw). The Mover product that you mention supports transfer [*from* Google Drive to FTP](http://support.mover.io/knowledgebase/articles/300998-transfer-from-google-drive-to-ftp), which is not what you want.

Comment: Are you using WordPress or any specific CMS?

Answer (score 0):

There is a free web-based cloud to cloud backup tool, MultCloud, which can help [back up FTP to Google Drive](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/sync-ftp-to-google-drive-1004.html) regularly. Click it to learn how it works.